# How is the Windows API/MFC handle event when window A contains window B?

Tags: wpf, winapi, mfc, activex

WPF use routed event which can route the event from one window to another. I am wondering how Windows API do for the event

Say, 2 Windows, Windows A and B, B is contained in A. When a mouse click event happened inside B, will the event be routed to both A and B or just B.

Comment: This is entirely up to *you*, there is no automatic bubbling of events from a child window to its parent.  Most child windows do something more useful, like letting the parent know that a *particular* part of the window got clicked.  The 150 horsepower chain-saw in your hands right now, nothing you cannot mow down with it.  Use it wisely.

Comment: I'm not sure the question is tagged ActiveX on purpose. Event handling with ActiveX is a different beast altogether. As for standard message handling: Message are usually sent to the window underneath the cursor (for mouse messages) or the window that has the keyboard focus (for keyboard messages). Exceptions are if a window is disabled: Messages are sent to the parent in this situation. Another exception are notifications: Those usually go to the parent as well. MFC is the same. It merely connects messages and message handlers, for better or worse.